# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Максимальное количество повторных попыток превышено с помощью url: /bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, ssl

Есть код:

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
import requests
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

# Создаем экземпляр бота и передаем токен
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

requests.get('https://api.telegram.org', verify=False)

# Подключаемся к Google Диску
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Обработчик команды "/start"
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    # Получаем список файлов с Google Диска
    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()

    # Создание подключения к базе данных
    conn = sqlite3.connect('file_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
                        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                         file_id TEXT,
                         telegram_id TEXT,
                         file_link TEXT)''')
    conn.commit()

    # Сохраняем ID файлов в базу данных, если они не были найдены
    for file in file_list:
        file_id = file['id']
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_id=?", (file_id,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO files (file_id) VALUES (?)", (file_id,))
            conn.commit()

    # Закрываем курсор после сохранения ID файлов
    cursor.close()

    # Открываем новый курсор для отправки файлов пользователю
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT file_id FROM files")
    existing_ids = set(row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall())
    for file in file_list:
        if file['id'] in existing_ids:
            file.GetContentFile(file['title'])  # Скачиваем файл
            with open(file['title'], 'rb') as f:
                sent_message = bot.send_document(message.chat.id, f)
                # Сохраняем Telegram ID файла в базе данных
                cursor.execute("UPDATE files SET telegram_id=? WHERE file_id=?", (sent_message.document.file_id, file['id']))
                conn.commit()
            # Создаем ссылку на файл
            file_link = f"https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{bot.token}/{bot.get_file(sent_message.document.file_id).file_path}"
            # Сохраняем ссылку в базе данных
            cursor.execute("UPDATE files SET file_link=? WHERE file_id=?", (file_link, file['id']))
            conn.commit()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    # Отправка ответного сообщения с ссылкой файла
    bot.reply_to(message, f'Cсылка на скачивание файла: {file_link}')

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=999)
```

Бот подключается к гугл диску, отправляет файлы пользователю и создает ссылку на скачивание файла, но проблема в том, что когда бот пытается отправить пользователю большой файл происходит ошибка: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Максимальное количество повторных попыток превышено с помощью url: /bot. Но это происходит только тогда, когда бот пытается отправить именно большеразмерный файл, когда файл весит несколько мб, то все работает как надо. Попробовал решить проблему отключением проверки, но не помогло. Объясните мне, может я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram API ограничивает размер файлов, которые можно отправить через бота. Максимальный размер файла 50МБ, для анимированных стикеров 1МБ.